# Logstash, how to marching log without any separator in it

Tags: logstash

my log example :

```
12345abcd?    abcd20211129113821.323
```

I'd like to get

```
data 1 => 12345 
data 2 => abcd? 
data 3 => abcd 
timestamp => 20211129113821.323
```

can you guys tell me how to march this kind a log with logstash, and what kind a filter I can use with this ?

Comment: One way to do what you want is the grok filter: [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html), [test tool](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), [basic patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/legacy/grok-patterns), [questions on the subject on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logstash+logstash-grok).

Comment: Now if you grok, you'll have to build a pattern, kinda like a regex. So if the different parts you want to extract have constant length, like 12345 will always be 5 characters, you'll use something like `(?<data_1>.{5})(?<data_2>.{5})`. If it's character types, you'll have to use something like `(?<data_1>[0-9]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

I advise to use grok pattern, for this you could used this online tools :
[grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

So for example with the sample of data you send, this pattern work perfectly :

```
%{INT:data1}%{NOTSPACE:data2}%{SPACE}%{DATA:data3}%{NUMBER:timestamp}
```